# Use Applescript to set the "Reply-To" address

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I have a registered domain, and I use hushmail as a mail provider. I'd like to send emails from Mail.app as if they were sent from my domain. The Hushmail SMTP server does not allow me to use a different "from" address than my account name, for security reasons (spam).

I found a way to have Apple mail fill the reply-to mail with a default all the time, here: http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/etalwaysreplyto.htm but that's too drastic for me, as I have multiple mail accounts in my mail client.

In Mail.app, I can set the "Reply to" field manually, but there is no setting in Mail.app to have that automatically filled based on the mailbox I select.

So far, I have an AppleScript which is able to create a reply on the selected mail:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    if theSelection is {} then return
    activate

    repeat with thisMessage in theSelection
        set theOutgoingMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window


        # Wait for Mail.app to create the reply window
        repeat until exists (window 1 whose name = "Re: " & subject of thisMessage)
        end repeat
        delay 0.1

        #
        # Here I want to set the reply-to address here based on the 
        # selected mailbox, or the "from" address of 
        # the current mail.
        #

        #
        # The I need to restore the cursor to the body of the mail 
        # (if cursor was moved)
        #
    end repeat
end tell
```

I've looked in the AppleScript Dictionary (File -> Open Dictionary -> Mail.app -> Message -> message -> reply to), and this seems to be a property I should be able to set, but when I do something like:

```
tell theOutgoingMessage
make new recipient at end of reply to with properties {address:"myreplyto@example.com"}
```

An error pops up saying "Mail got an error: Can't get reply to of outgoing message id 65."

I also tried

```
tell theOutgoingMessage
set reply to to "myreplyto@example.com"
```

But that pops up an error saying "Mail got an error: Can’t set reply to of outgoing message id 69 to "myreplyto@example.com".

How can I set the reply-to property of the reply mail I just created?

Comment: Looking in the dictionary shows this... reply to (text, r/o). The r/o means this is a read-only property so you won't be able to set it programatically. You can only read it programatically. As such you'll have to do it with ui element scripting techniques.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments to your post, you can't set the reply-to address programmatically because it's a read-only property. Therefore you need to ui script this solution.

The problem with ui scripting is that it's not an exact science. If Apple changes the positioning of the ui elements then your script will stop working. For example, I have Mail.app v6.5 and the reply-to field can be referenced using "text field 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1". In other versions of Mail.app that could be different (and probably is).

Anyway, in v6.5 of Mail.app this will do what you want using ui scripting.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    if theSelection is {} then return
    activate

    repeat with thisMessage in theSelection
        set replyToAddress to item 1 of (get email addresses of account of mailbox of thisMessage)
        set replyToWindowName to subject of thisMessage
        if replyToWindowName does not start with "Re:" then set replyToWindowName to "Re: " & replyToWindowName

        -- open the reply message
        set theOutgoingMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window

        -- Wait for Mail.app to create the reply window
        repeat until exists (window 1 whose name is replyToWindowName)
            delay 0.2
        end repeat

        -- make sure the reply-to field is showing
        my openReplyToField()

        -- set the reply-to address here based on the selected mailbox
        my setValueOfReplyToField(replyToAddress)
    end repeat
end tell

on openReplyToField()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            -- figure out if the reply-to text field is visible
            set staticText to value of every static text of window 1
            if staticText contains "Reply To:" then return

            -- the reply-to field is not visible so we click the menu item
            set viewMenu to menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
            set replyToMenuItem to first menu item of viewMenu whose name contains "Reply-To"
            click replyToMenuItem
        end tell
    end tell
end openReplyToField

on setValueOfReplyToField(theValue)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            set replyToField to text field 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
            set value of replyToField to theValue
        end tell
    end tell
end setValueOfReplyToField
```

Comment: Very promising. I have Mail 6.3, and the script doesn't work out of the box but I'm trying to combine ideas. Your script has some great pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
make new recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"myreplyto@example.com"}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It adds a recipient in the "To": field, but not to the "Reply-To" field. For clarity: The Reply-To field becomes visible when you select View -> Reply-To Address Field.

Comment: Ops, you are right, I see now.
From Mail AppleScript dictionary, it seems that the outgoing message class doesn't support the reply to property.
I think the only solution is to script the gui, adding the following code to the end of your script:

tell application "System Events"
set value of (text field 1) of scroll area 1 of front window of application process "Mail" to "myreplyto@example.com"
end tell